# How to Check more than one item in the checkbox in Java

Tags: java

I am creating a simple inventory system in java. While I am creating the project I ran in to the problem with I have 3 items (fried rice, chicken, fish). If I checked more then one item and add the quantity next the text box it should added into the table.

I don't  how to add quantity to text boxes there are 3 text boxes there. How to add the quantity text box I don't know If I select chicken and fish and add the quantity next the text box it should added in to the table,

[image]

**Code:**

```
if(lblfried.isSelected() == true)
{
   int price = 12;
   String name = lblfried.getText();   
}
else if(lblfish.isSelected() == true)
{
  int price = 15;
  String  name = lblfish.getText();    
}
 else if(lblchicken.isSelected() == true)
{
    int  price = 25;
    String name =lblchicken.getText();    
}   


int tot = qty * price;
model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();      
DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
jTable1.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, centerRenderer);
model.addRow(new Object[]
{         
    name,
    price,
    qty,
    tot,
});           

int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < jTable1.getRowCount(); i++)
{
    sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(jTable1.getValueAt(i, 3).toString());
} 

txtsub.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
```

Comment: `JLabel.CENTER` as a parameter for a `TableCellRenderer`?

Comment: 1. Use `if` instead of `else if` if you really want to check for multiple selections 2. show us how you get the `qty`

Comment: It sounds like you really want a radio button. And never compare `isSelected() == true`--it's already either true or false.

Comment: if i select chicken and fish and add the qty next the textbox it should added in to the table

Comment: i don't how to write the code sir please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is issue with your approach, as given below:

- Using `if-else` makes the code to detect only one check box and skip the remaining no matter if they are checked or not.
- You are using same variable `qty` to calculate total at the end of all `if-else`. All of your text boxes having quantity **MUST** have different name check the names and replace them in the given code.
- You need to create table first then check and calculates the attributes that will be shown in the table, so you can add them afterwards.

**Code:**

```
// Make table above all this, so you can add rows afterwards
model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();      
DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
jTable1.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, centerRenderer);

int sum = 0; // You can maintain sum here, then "For-loop" can be skipped
// Now if checkBox is checked just add the row into table
if(lblfried.isSelected())
{  
   int qty = Integer.parseInt(qty_fried.getText());
   model.addRow(new Object[]
    {         
        lblfried.getText(), // name 
        12,                 // price  
        qty_fried.getText(),// quantity <- replace this 
        qty * 12           // total
    }); 
    sum += qty * 12;
}
if(lblfish.isSelected())
{
   int qty = Integer.parseInt(qty_fish.getText());
    model.addRow(new Object[]
    {         
        lblfish.getText(), 
        15,                   
        qty_fish.getText(),               
        qty * 15
    });  
    sum += qty * 15;
}
if(lblchicken.isSelected())
{
   int qty = Integer.parseInt(qty_chicken.getText());
    model.addRow(new Object[]
    {         
        lblchicken.getText(), 
        25,                   
        qty_chicken.getText(),               
        qty * 25
    });    
    sum += qty * 25;
}   

txtsub.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
```

**Note:** You should take care of all the variables that you have used as I can't replicate your variables name in my code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly whast you mean. It could be because you are using `else if` statements, now when, say fried rice, is selected then it is now skipping the other checks and going straight to creating the table. Try just using multiple `if` statements, although you are also creating new `price` variables and assigning them each time.

Comment: how to do the qty part sir there are 3 textboxs avalible

Comment: ```Integer.parseInt(textField.getText())``` where you can replace ```textField``` with the name of each text field